# In Torch / Lua, is there a command to analyze an object (like str() in R)?

Tags: data-structures, lua, torch

I have to analyze some objects and their structure in my Torch / Lua script.
I would like to use a command that behave like [`str()` in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/str.html).

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use a [serializer](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization) to represent complex data structures in a readable way. There is [torch.serialize](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/serialization.md) function, but it doesn't produce human-readable output. I've written [Serpent serializer and pretty-printer](https://github.com/pkulchenko/serpent) that supports some of the options that `str()` has, like the max nesting level for tables or the max number of elements in a table. It also supports custom formatters, which allows you to modify the output to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

I like this module: https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua

`luarocks install inspect`

then import it like this

`local inspect = require 'inspect'`

output may be something like this:

```
assert(inspect(setmetatable({a=1}, {b=2}) == [[{
  a = 1
  <metatable> = {
    b = 2
  }
}]]))
```

common usage:

```
print(inspect(myobj))
```